# TFT vs XWGA, WSVGA

Tags: netbook, display

I'm looking for a netbook, but i really don't know which is the difference between those technologies. Which is the best for outdoor use of a netbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFT is a type of display technology ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_transistor). It's pretty standard. I'm not sure you'll do better, unless you're looking at E-Ink type technology, which is fine for reading books outside but which isn't so great (just MHO) for many other computer tasks.

XWGA and WSVGA are resolution settings ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution).

- XWGA - looks like a typo of WXGA - 1280 x 768 (widescreen format)
- WSVGA - 1024 x 600 (widescreen format).

One word of warning: more is not always better ( [Linux virtualized screen resolution](https://superuser.com/questions/143891/linux-virtualized-screen-resolution)). I'm also finding my 1920 x 1200 screen to be a real pain in the tail because all the text is too small, although 1920 x 1080 is the screensize for HD video.

Instead of trying to evaluate different technologies, I suggest looking for reviews of particular products. At the end of the day, it's all about the implementation.

Comment: eric hit the mark with his answer. also, i would suggest avoiding anything with a "glossy" screen; its mostly a marketing gimmick and just makes your screen unusable in sunlight.